# Adding attributes to HTML tags in Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I want to validate a phone number and make sure the user enters all 10 digits. This can be done using the HTML5 pattern atribute:

```
<input pattern=".{10,}" title="10 characters minimum">
```

How can I add this pattern attribute to my input tag in Contact Form 7 ?

This what the mobile number input shortcode looks like:

`[text* mobile id:field-mobile]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `tel` shortcode to do this:

```
[tel* id:field-mobile 10/10 "placeholder text"]
```

This brings up the issue of browser support; if the browser in use does not support the `tel` input type, it will fall back to a plain text field.

Source: http://contactform7.com/text-fields/ (halfway down the page)